Looking for an old Chinese cowboy film
I watched this film circa 1995 from a VHS recorded by my father from a Hong Kong TV channel. I only remember some scenes, but I also remember that I liked this film a lot when I was a kid. The film is probably older than 1995.
From what I remember, it was about a Chinese/Mongolian (I don't remember the details very well) shepherd/cowboy who had a hidden talent for swordmanship. The main protagonist (the cowboy), and pretty much all the characters in the movie, wore fur clothes similar to this one: 

Chinese man wearing furs (but more dirty). The scenarios of the film were predominatly steppes or something similar to a desert.
The final act ends in a duel (like the typical western duels at high noon but with swords instead of guns) against an evil bandit. The hero manages to win the fight with a single slash (like in some samurai movies), but he also takes a slash the would leave a pretty big scar accross his face in exchange.

Was it black and white or color?

It was in color. The photography wasn't very old. It looked like it was filmed between the 80s and early 90s

Do you remember anything about the plot, like what the protagonist's objective was, or some conflict in the movie?

Vaguely. I remember there was a romantic interest, a girl who was in arranged marriage with the protagonist because he saved her father or some people of a near village (those details are very blurry in my memories) from a bandit and didn't like him in the beginning because of his humble roots. I believe the main antagonist (the bandit leader) wanted to kill the hero and raid the village as a revenge against the protagonist and he were all the movie thinking that the guy only had luck when he fought his subordinates the first time

Found it! After so many years! The film in question was "Swordsmen in Double Flag Town" also known as "Swordsman in Double Flag Town". Here's the Wikipedia article about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swordsmen_in_Double_Flag_Town

Well done for finding it, does sound like an interesting movie.
